# EF Core Data annotation Must be greater than an other field

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, data-annotations

This is model class to generate a table.

```
 public class Mission
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Range(minimum: 1, maximum: int.MaxValue)]
    public int MinDayRate { get; set; }
    [Range(minimum: 1, maximum: int.MaxValue)]
    public int MaxDayRate { get; set; }
}
```

In SQL Server it's :
ALTER TABLE Mission ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MaxDayRate_vs_MinDayRate
CHECK (MinDayRate <= MaxDayRate );

How can I create a Data annotation MaxDayRate must be greater than MinDayRate that will create the constraint as in my sql server sample ?

Comment: Not by attributes but via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.hascheckconstraint?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a data annotation `[Compare]`. However, `[Compare]` checks that the two properties are equal, not that one is larger than the other. There does exist [EFCore.CheckConstraints](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.CheckConstraints) which applies various .NET validation attributes as database check constraints.

A better way is to define any check constraint with the exact SQL in the OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
    .HasCheckConstraint("CK_Properties_MinDayRate_MaxDayRate", "[MaxDayRate] > [MinDayRate]");
```

Answer (score 1):

The question asked how to create a Data Annotation to accomplish comparing one property with another.  The annotation is called a Validation Attribute and is probably better to keep validation within the class than to use a database table constraint.  Attributes are already being used so just continue.  Comparing properties with each other for validation purposes occurs sometimes so its better to learn how to do this using Custom Attributes that you write yourself.  This way you can validate almost any scenario you can think of.

```
public class CompareDayRatesAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public CompareDayRatesAttribute() { }

    public string GetErrorMessage() =>
        $"MaxDayRate must be more than MinDayRate";

    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(
        object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var mission = (Mission)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var maxDayRate = (int)value;

        if (maxDayRate < mission.MinDayRate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

The new class looks like this:

```
public class Mission
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Range(minimum: 1, maximum: int.MaxValue)]
    public int MinDayRate { get; set; }

    [CompareDayRates()]
    [Range(minimum: 1, maximum: int.MaxValue)]
    public int MaxDayRate { get; set; }
}
```